# Jackson is adding redundant data to POJO and then can't read it back

Tags: json, jackson

I am using Jackson in order to send data in JSON type between a client a server.
I am trying to use Jackson's full binding feature and I am applying it over a standard POJO.
The problem is that Jackson seem to add redundant data during marshaling on the server so when I try to unmarshall it back to the POJO on the client side I'm getting an error.

Here's an excerpt of the Jackson String:

{"_class":"com.mycoomp.MyObject","_id":{"time":1300314145000,"new":false,"machine":1652794940,"inc":-510750341},"language":"","type".....

MyObject contains "language" and "type" but it it doesn't contain “time”, “new” and “machine” that are not part of it but on the client side i'm getting this error:

Unrecognized field "time" (Class org.bson.types.ObjectId), not marked as ignorable at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1c56c60; line: 1, column: 102] (through reference chain: com.mycomp.MyObject["_id"]->org.bson.types.ObjectId["time"])

Any ideas...?

Comment: Please add full definition of POJO (MyObject?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give type definitions for types you are serializing. Jackson does not add any entries that are not discoverable from objects (via getters, public fields, or explicitly annotated); except in cases where you add @JsonTypeInfo annotation to also add type identifier.

So maybe object you are serializing has more public fields that will be serialized?

Comment: My POJO doesn't have any annotations on it. Even if it has more public fields why will Jackson add fields that don't exist?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to give type definitions for types I want to serialize?

Comment: You don't need to give definitions, Jackson will figure out things from the class definition (but these can be overridden by annotations if you want). That's why it is necessary to know class definition -- without that it's not possible to know what happens. Jackson does not add stuff that is not there; but maybe there are public fields or get methods you didn't think are? Some frameworks do add things, for AOP and such.

Comment: Ok I've got more details on the problem. My POJO contains a class member with type org.bson.types.ObjectId which is s globally unique identifier for objects in mongodb and this one has these members in it (see http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html). It appears that even though Jackson is able to Marshall this object into Json, it is unable to unmarshall it back to the bean object. To recreate the problem simply create a bean that has org.bson.types.ObjectId and use Jackson's native mapper methods to read and then write that bean.

Comment: Ok. Then you need a custom serializer and/or deserializer -- mongo types are not supported out of the boxes (since no deps to third party libs will be added). Maybe ask on the user list if someone else has already done it: there is a good chance someone has.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to provide a custom serializer/deserializer for ObjectId:

```
public class ObjectIdMapping {
    public static class ObjectIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ObjectId>{
        @Override
        public void serialize(ObjectId  id, JsonGenerator json,
                SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
                JsonProcessingException {
            json.writeString(id.toString());

        }
    }
    public static class ObjectIdDeerializer extends JsonDeserializer<ObjectId>{
        @Override
        public ObjectId deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            if (!ObjectId.isValid(jp.getText())) throw context.mappingException("invalid ObjectId " + jp.getText());
            return new ObjectId(jp.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

And register them as any of the methods described in [the documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers). For example, add in your POJO:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdMapping.ObjectIdSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = ObjectIdMapping.ObjectIdDeerializer.class)
public ObjectId od;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across this as I had the same problem. Seems like a job for the [mongo-jackson-mapper](http://vznet.github.com/mongo-jackson-mapper/)

I would also advise taking infrastructural classes such as ObjectId out of your domain.